# Is there an array version of $1...$NF in awk?

Tags: arrays, awk

Consider the following function which is currently in the public domain.

```
function join(array, start, end, sep, result, i)
{
    if (sep == "")
       sep = " "
    else if (sep == SUBSEP) # magic value
       sep = ""
    result = array[start]
    for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
        result = result sep array[i]
    return result
}
```

I would like to use this function join contiguous columns such as `$2, $3, $4` where the start and end ranges are variables.

However, in order to do this, I must first convert all the fields into an array using a loop like the following.

```
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    a[i] = $i    
}
```

Or the shorter version, as @StevenPenny mentioned.

```
split($0, a)
```

Unfortunately both approaches require the creation of a new variable.

Does awk have a built-in way of accessing the columns as an array so that the above manual conversions are not necessary?

Comment: Cant you just do `split($0, a)` ?

Comment: @StevenPenny, Absolutely and I will edit that into the question, but it is still involves creating a new variable.

Comment: @merlin2011 why do you need them in an array ? They are already set as variable that you can just loop to, and as all variables in awk are global then passing anything to the function isn't really needed, unless you want to have an array unique to the function, in which case you will need to create a new variable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No such array is [defined in POSIX `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) (the only array type special variables are `ARGV` and `ENVIRON`).

None exists in `gawk` either, though it adds `PROCINFO`, `SYMTAB` and `FUNCTAB` special arrays. You can check all the defined variables and types at runtime using  the `SYMTAB` array (gawk-4.1.0 feature):

```
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" }  # automagic sort for "in"
{ print $0 }
END   { for (ss in SYMTAB) printf("%-12s: %s\n",PROCINFO["identifiers"][ss],ss)  }
```

(though you will find that `SYMTAB` and `FUNCTAB` themselves are missing from the list, and missing from `--dump-variables` too, they are treated specially by design).
gawk also offers a few standard loadable extensions, none implements this feature though (and given the dynamic relation ship between `$0`, `$1`..., `NF` and `OFS`, an array that had the same functionality would be a little tricky to implement).

As suggested by Jidder, one work-around is to skip the array altogether and use fields. There's nothing special about the field names, a variable `$n` can be used the same as a literal like `$1` (just take care to use braces for precedence in expressions like `$(NF-1)`. Here's an `fjoin` function which works on fields rather than an array:

```
function fjoin(start,end,sep,    result,ii) {
    if (sep=="") sep=" "
    else if (sep==SUBSEP) sep =""
    result=$start
    for (ii=start+1; ii<=end; ii++) 
        result=result sep $ii
    return result
}

{ print "2,4: " fjoin(2,4,":") }
```

(this does not treat `$0` as a special case)

Or just use `split()` and be happy, gawk at least guarantees that it behaves identically to field splitting (assuming that none of `FS`, `FIELDWIDTHS` and possibly `IGNORECASE` are being modified so as to change the behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

this is what i do in my own code

```
function iter0gen() { 
   
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"; # skip this for mawk

   return split(sprintf("%0"(NF)"d", 0), iter0, //) 
}
```

since splitting by null string means 1-char per bin, then just split a string of zeros with length equal to that of NF, create an array called iter0, then you can do

```
for (x in iter0) { $(x) = do stuff….. }
```

This is only for if you need a lazy iterator. The plus side of this is that since indices begin at 1 by default, u can't accidentally get $0 in the iterator loop. The down side of this is that if you're not careful, you would've switched all the input FS into OFS the moment you assign into any field, and this doesn't pre-backup $0 on ur behalf.

if you just want the columns, then just do standard `split()` of the array using `FS`. If you're using gawk and would like the seps array too, then add that optional 4th argument that's non-portable.